How is Neal's Algorithm 1 derived?
I'm reading through Markov Chain Sampling Methods for Dirichlet Process Mixture Model by Neal. I'm having trouble understanding how Equations 3.2,3.3, and 3.4 were derived. They make intuitive sense, but I'm having trouble coming up with a formal derivation, in particular equation 3.4.
From the paper:

This is what I have (incorrect?)
$$\begin{align*}
p(\theta_i|\theta_{-i}, y_i)&\propto p(\theta_i, \theta_{-i}, y_i)\\
&=p(y_i|\theta_i, \theta_{-i})p(\theta_i|\theta_{-i})p(\theta_{-i})\\
&=p(y_i|\theta_i)p(\theta_i|\theta_{-i})p(\theta_{-i}) \quad\text{since}\;{y_i\perp \theta_{-i}|\theta_i}\\
&\propto p(y_i|\theta_i)p(\theta_i|\theta_{-i})
\end{align*}$$
I'm not sure where the integral comes from.
